# Exporting data factory pipelines

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to export my data factory pipelines as a backup but the problem is that i have to export each individual pipeline JSON file from the code.
Is there an easier way of exporting all at once or atleast export the whole folder with all the underlying pipelines in it along with the sub folder structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export the entire data factory as an ARM template.
Go to manage -> ARM template, and click on Export ARM template.
[image: export ARM template]

If you want to extract the pipelines from the ARM template, you can use code to write each pipeline to it's own file.
Here is an example in Python:

```
import json
with open("ARMTemplateForFactory.json","r") as ARM:
    data = json.load(ARM)
for resource in data["resources"]:
    if resource["type"]=="Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines":
        #print(data["resources"][0]["name"][37:-3])
        resource_name = str(resource["name"])
        file_name = resource_name[str(resource_name).find(",")+4:-3]
        print(file_name)
        pl_file = open(file_name+".json","x")
        #pl_file.write(str(resource))
        json.dump(resource,pl_file)
        pl_file.close()
```

ARMTemplateForFactory.json is the file extracted from the ARM template zip file.

Comment: That is for whole data factory. I need to script one Pipeline. Is there any way ?

Comment: I edited the answer and added some code to extract the pipelines from the ARM template.